# PHP searching for a string in a file

Tags: php, string, count

I'm looking for a function that counts the number of times a string occurs within a file, I tried using `$count = preg_match_all("/String/", $file, $matches);` but it returns `Warning: preg_match_all() expects parameter 2 to be string, resource given`. Is there any function that allows me to do this with a file, instead of a string, or is there any way to assign a file to a string (I assume the latter would be a lot slower)?

Comment: You need to pass a string value to the 2nd parameter. Perhaps you can do: `file_get_contents($filename)` for that argument.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

yes:

> `file_get_contents()` — Reads entire file into a string

http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php

so for you it would be

```
$file = file_get_contents(PATH_TO_FILE);
$count = preg_match_all("/String/", $file, $matches);
```

I'm guessing you have used `fopen` instead by mistake?

Comment: Yes, I've been using `fopen`, but `file_get_contents` is exactly what I needed. Thank you.

Answer (score 9):

```
$count = substr_count(file_get_contents($file), $string);
```

Manual:
[substr_count](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr-count.php)
[file_get_contents](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php)